# Screen turns on and off when using Unity dash or browsers

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, dell, radeon

Just got new laptop and had to set up ubuntu 14.04 on it. It's a Dell Inspiration 7000 Series 7548. One of those fancy 4K displays with touchscreen. It has 2 video cards (according to `lspci | grep VGA`):

- Intel Integrated Graphics
- Radeon R7 M265

Now the biggest problem I'm facing is that the screen starts turning on and off (or at least it turns black and when i move my mouse it turns back on for a moment) when I'm using Unity dash or browser url bars. Other than that UI seems to be a little slow with animations and some programs are unusable (PhpStorm editor is unreadable).

Edit 1:
Output from `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'; aticonfig --pxl` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Subsystem: Dell Device 066f


Kernel driver in use: i915
--
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265]
    Subsystem: Dell Device 066f
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
PowerXpress: Discrete GPU is active (High-Performance mode).
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'; aticonfig --pxl` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 , Ive added the output

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: This may be a hardware problem.

Comment: Laptop came with pre-installed Windows 8.1 and it seemed to be working fine. I didn't spend too much time exploring it but there were no visible issues

Answer (score 1):

Install AMD drivers by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and reboot.

You can switch to the Intel adapter by

```
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu
```

and restart the session or reboot.

Comment: Already have it, and using it. Also have X. Org X server and just fglrx

Comment: Unfortunately the updated answer didn't help either. After reboot it took a while to load and the issue started appearing the moment I turned the browser (Chrome) on. I noticed that touching the touchpad (but not moving mouse) prevents flickering from happening. But moving the mouse makes it switch on and off. If I open terminal for example, the screen behaves like it should and no flickering happens